# What is the best way to perform parallel execution inside a web servlet?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

Spawning threads inside web servlet is not the correct way. Executor Services are best prescribed for asynchronous operations (is it?)
If one needs to perform multiple parallel operations and combine the results in the same webservlet response, then what would be a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement multiple servlet responses using Spring MVC concept or struts frame work it can be done easily.
Just go through the following link
http://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-interceptors-tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm